# Improper installation of Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I execute `create-react-app` on my windows pc, only dependencies get installed with no folders except for `node_modules`, I haven't gone really far even while using `Yarn`. Please help and thanks in advance. This is what I get

```
C:\Users\Arsh Deep\Desktop>create-react-app myapp2

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Arsh Deep\Desktop\myapp2.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 23 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-scripts@3.4.3
└─ react@16.13.1
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions@7.11.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.10.4
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.11.0
├─ @babel/preset-typescript@7.9.0
├─ babel-preset-react-app@9.1.2
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
├─ html-entities@1.3.1
├─ loglevel@1.7.0
├─ portfinder@1.0.28
├─ react-dev-utils@10.2.1
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.7
├─ react-scripts@3.4.3
├─ react@16.13.1
├─ scheduler@0.19.1
├─ serialize-javascript@4.0.0
├─ sockjs@0.3.20
├─ spdy@4.0.2
├─ terser-webpack-plugin@2.3.8
└─ webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
Done in 17.84s.
```

Comment: You are missing `npx` so it should be `npx create-react-app myapp2
`

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This may have happened due to either a slow network or due to create-react-app version,

```
 1. Try to update the create-react-app version
 2. Or best uninstall create-react-app and use npx create-react-app to create react scaffold
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be caused by a few issues.

if previously you haven't had this problem, I recommend you check your connection or change it for trying again if it's possible.

secondly, try to update your  tools

try this out with npm and then make a new project with create-react-app

```
   npm rm -g create-react-app
   npm install -g create-react-app
   npx create-react-app my-app
```